# Почему Static API отражает разный масштаб в зависимости от координат центра карты

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

Вот две карты:

```
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?size=650,414&ll=37.54,55.84&spn=0.01,0.01&l=map
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
https://static-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?size=650,414&ll=37.54,55.83&spn=0.01,0.01&l=map
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что карты отличаются только координатой широты: 55.84 vs 55.83

Однако масштаб показываемых карт отличается. Это хорошо видно по схеме водоема или по схеме парка около Тимирязевской улицы.

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вычислить масштаб, указанная географическая область проецируется на сервере на плоскость. Масштаб подбирается так, чтобы проекция целиком помещалась в указанные размеры карты. 
Поскольку Земля - это шар, при проецировании на плоскость размеры немного искажаются. Участки, близкие к полюсам, как бы растягиваются вширь. Поэтому при изменении широты масштаб карты будет меняться при прочих равных параметрах.
Если важно задать определенный масштаб карты, можно воспользоваться параметром `z`, который задаёт [коэффициент масштабирования карты](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/staticapi/1.x/dg/concepts/map_scale-docpage/?from=SO).

Comment: Мне кажется, для полноценности вопроса-ответа стоит написать, как этого избежать

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, добавила)

Comment: Всё равно непонятно, 0.01 градус широты не должен влиять настолько сильно.